# JavaScript find and remove an element from an array using splice not supported in IE9

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer-9, array-splice

I have an array in JavaScript and I need to find a specific element and remove it. I tried with `splice()` and `findIndex()` and it's not supported in JSEclipse nor in IE9. I used `splice()` and `find()` and it doesn't work in IE9.

There are 2 points why my question is not a duplicate: 
(1) My array is an array of objects so using `indexOf()` does not apply.
(2) Support in IE9 is prerequisite for my solutions.

I would appreciate any assistant.

My array:

```
var portingOptions = [
   {
      name: 'print',
      iconClass: 'faxBlue'
   },
   {
      name: 'pdf',
      iconClass: 'pdfBlue'
   },
   {
      name: 'exportToCcr',
      iconClass: 'documentBlue'

   },
   {
      name: 'message',
      iconClass: 'secureMessageBlue'
   },
   {
      name: 'email',
      iconClass: 'emailBlue'
   }
];
```

My code with `splice()` and `find()`:

```
if (myParameters.removeEmailField) {
   portingOptions.splice(portingOptions.find(function(element) {
      return element.name === 'email';
      })
   );
}
```

Does anyone know of a solution that will work on IE9?

Comment: You can use polyfill for `filter`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: It's not a duplicate as I can't use `indexOf()` - my array is an array of objects and using `indexOf()` does not apply to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery methods [$.grep()](http://$.grep()) to replace your `Array.find()`

`Array.splice()` instead seems to be supported from IE 5.5

There is also a nice polyfill that should work on IE9:

```
Array.prototype.find = Array.prototype.find || function(callback) {
  if (this === null) {
    throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined');
  } else if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
    throw new TypeError('callback must be a function');
  }
  var list = Object(this);
  // Makes sures is always has an positive integer as length.
  var length = list.length >>> 0;
  var thisArg = arguments[1];
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var element = list[i];
    if ( callback.call(thisArg, element, i, list) ) {
      return element;
    }
  }
```

Ref:https://github.com/jsPolyfill/Array.prototype.find/blob/master/find.js

Comment: I can only use JavaScript, jQuery is not included in our project.

Comment: Update the answer with a polyfill

Comment: Please read my question carefully: I tried using `find()`, but it's not supported in IE9. Removing an element from an array in JavaScript is not a problem, my challenge is to do it in a way that is supported in IE9. This is condition to the solution.

Comment: Read carefully my answer, if `Array.find()`does not exists, a polyfill is applied and you'll have an `Array.find()` also in IE9

Answer (score 0):

You could take a while loop, instead of `find`, which is not implemented.

If you like to remove more than one, remove `break` statement.

```
var index = array.length;

while (index--) {
    if (array[index].name === 'email') {
        array.splice(index, 1);
        break;
    }
}
```